# Python MacOS save Outlook attachments to disk

Tags: python, macos, outlook, download, email-attachments

Using MacOS, I would like Python code that downloads Outlook attachments between two dates.

The following won't save the files:

```
    for attachment in attachments:
        # Get the attachment name
        attachment_name = attachment.name()
    
        # Save the attachment to the specified directory
        print("Attachment saved:", attachment.name())
        file_path = os.path.join(save_folder, attachment.name())
        # attachment.save(in_=file_path)
        attachment.save(file_path)
    
        num_attachments += 1
```

Comment: `attachments` is not defined. The question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example